# An ordinary differential equation with non Lipschitz RHS

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have the following initial value problem: 
>   $$\tag{IVP}\label{IVP}
> \begin{cases}
> x^\prime(t) = -\sqrt[3]{x}\\
> x(0) = x_0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   and I have to show that for every $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ a solution to \eqref{IVP} exists and it is unique.

Existence is not an issue, as the function $f(x) := -\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous, hence [Peano's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) applies. But what about uniqueness?

Here are my considerations. As long as the solution is positive/negative it is decreasing/increasing. Let us suppose $x_0<0$. Then for $t$ small enough it remains negative so that I can divide 
$$
\frac{x^\prime(t)}{\sqrt[3]{x}} = -1
$$
which by integration yields
$$
\int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \frac{dy}{\sqrt[3]{y}} = - t, \qquad \text{i.e. } x(t) = \left(-\frac{2}{3}t + x_0^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}
$$
and here comes already a problem: the formula I have found implies $x\ge 0$ (it is a square root!). Where am I mistaken? How can I show uniqueness? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the definition of $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ is ambiguous, if $x>0$ then there is no problem, i.e this is $x^\frac{1}{3}$, but for $x<0$ you can not use such formula so I suppose the definition is:
$$\sqrt[3]{x}=sgn(x) |x|^\frac{1}{3}$$
in particular the antiderivative for $x <0$ is not $\frac{3}{2} x^\frac{2}{3}$ but $sgn(x) \frac{3}{2} x^\frac{2}{3}$.

---

To be more precise as long as $x(t)<0$ with $z(t)=-x(t)>0$ we have:
$$-z'(t)=+z(t)^\frac{1}{3}$$
so:
$$z(t)=\left(z_0^\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}t \right)^\frac{3}{2}$$
i.e in terms of $x$:
$$x(t)=-\left((-x_0)^\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}t \right)^\frac{3}{2}$$
which is indeed negative and well defined fot $t<\frac{3}{2} (-x_0)^\frac{2}{3}$.

---

For uniqueness, the only case remaining is when $x$ touches $0$ (or $x_0=0$). But with $n(t)=x(t)^2 \geq 0$ you have:
$$n'(t)=2 x(t) x'(t) = - 2 |x|^\frac{4}{3} \leq 0$$
so $n$ is non increasing. In particular if $x(t^*)=0$ then for all $t \geq t^*$ we have $n(t)=0$ i.e $x(t)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes a lot of sense. Btw, we now have the explicit formula of the solution for $x_0<0$, as far as the solution remains negative. What happens when it touches $0$? Since I do not know a priori uniqueness it may continue being $0$... or not? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "the definition of $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ is ambiguous". The function $x\mapsto x^3$ is invertible in $\mathbb{R}$ so for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a unique $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y^3=x$ i.e. $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Indeed, it is just that the function $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ and $\cdot^\frac{1}{3}$ are not the same and the usual rules (derivatives, antiderivatives, etc.) are for the second one :-)

Comment: @the-yellow-bishop For the uniqueness, as you said the only point remaining is the case when $x$ touches $0$ i.e $x_0=0$. In this case there is usually some problems (for example $x'=|x|^\frac{1}{3}$ does not have uniqueness) but here you can use the fact that $x(t) \times x'(t) \leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your expansion of the answer, I am puzzled in view of Rigel's answer. Just give me some time to focus better, thanks again for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2):

For $x_0 = 0$ there is multiplicity of solutions.
Indeed, one solution is $x(t) \equiv 0$, and another one is
$$
y(t) :=
\begin{cases}
(-\frac{2}{3} t)^{3/2}, & \text{if}\ t < 0,\\
0, & \text{if}\ t \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Uh, this is surprising. Indeed, I have been taught that if one has a (first order) ODE with continuous, non-increasing RHS then uniqueness holds. This was - I supposed - an exercise given so to "touch by hands" this theorem. I am very puzzled, but thanks for your answer, I need some time to digest.

Comment: @the-yellow-bishop It depends of what you mean by "uniqueness": as Rigel pointed out there is multiple functions $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ solutions of the equation with $x(0)=0$. But there is only one function $x: [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ solution of the equation such that $x(0)=0$.

Comment: @the-yellow-bishop In your case, the uniqueness holds **to the right of $t_0=0$**.

Comment: Oh right, this makes perfectly sense. So basically the situation is the following: for every $t_0 \ne 0$ we have uniqueness for every $t$. For $t_0=0$ we have uniqueness only to the right, as Rigel's counterexample shows. Is this eventually correct? Thank you very much, this has been very helpful.

Comment: @the-yellow-bishop if by $t_0$ you mean $x_0$ this is indeed correct :-).

Comment: @Delta-u Sure, thanks I meant $x_0$. Thanks a lot for your help. ;-) I hope Rigel won't mind if I accept your answer, which also came first chronologically. Thanks to all of you!